# Functional monotone class theorem on uncountable generated sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

the [functional monotone class theorem](http://planetmath.org/proofoffunctionalmonotoneclasstheorem/%22functional%20monotone%20class%20theorem%22) states that if a random variable $X$ is measurable to the sigma algebra generated by another random variable $Y:\Omega\rightarrow E$, i.e. $\sigma(Y)$, then $X=g(Y)$ for some measurable function $g:E \rightarrow \Bbb R$.

**Question:** If $X$ is measurable to some sigma algebra generated by uncountable random variable, such as the natural filtration of a stochastic process $Y_t$ at time $t$. What can be said about measurability of $X$. Can I still find a functional representation as in functional monotone class theorem?